Why am I getting "The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 9.0. " when I have .Net 9 Preview Installed?
I would like to try the new .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid and Web App template.  I installed the latest .NET 9 Preview but I am getting the below errors when the template is immediately opened / built.


I have the latest VS installed. 17.11.3
I have .Net 9 Preview 7 Installed on my machine.   Why am I getting the errors?


I believe .NET 9 preview is only available in VS 2022 v17.12 preview editions - see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-9-preview-7/ - quote: If you’re on Windows using Visual Studio, we recommend installing the latest Visual Studio 2022 preview. .NET 9 can now be installed directly through the Visual Studio installer starting with Visual Studio 2022 17.12 Preview 1 .

I see.  I will wait until November then.   Thank you Marc!

I learned that you can still use VS 2022 with .Net 9 Preview by selecting the below Option.  I still can't run the NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid and Web App template in VS 2022 but I can use .Net 9 with my Blazor Web App and use the enhanced Rejoining Server Mechanism which saves time.


I encountered bugs running .NET 9 Preview.  I switched this feature off and when back to .NET 8.
